# How to overlay color of element 1 on the color of body or element 2?

Tags: html, css

In my html I have given body a color and I need to place another element of its own color over it. I have already tried using position relative and absolute with z-index.

Here's the body tag.

```
<body bgcolor="cyan" style="position: relative;">
```

Here's the another element.

```
<p class="content">a</p>
```

Here's css I used by searching online.

```
.content{
position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems right here! just remove `display:none` from your css

```
.content{
position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
z-index: 10;
}
```

Now this should appear as you are expecting it !